# Why does my system count /media for disk space?

Tags: debian, disk-usage

I'm running debian

```
# uname -a
Linux thinkstation 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1 (2018-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

after booting today I got an error that the system wasn't able to write to `/tmp` because of lack of space. So I started to delete some old kernels. I'm now able to log into the system but I'm still confused about my system disk space usage:

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            8.9G     0  8.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G  9.4M  1.8G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        83G   78G  210M 100% /
tmpfs           8.9G  117M  8.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           8.9G     0  8.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6       357G   48G  292G  14% /home
tmpfs           1.8G   20K  1.8G   1% /run/user/1000
```

As you can see my root partition seems to be full. Here is how I partitioned my system:

```
# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  83.9G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  18.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0 363.2G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

As you can see I've separated my home from my system (and a separate swap as well). Now if I dive into what is causing the disk usage in `/` I via ncdu I get the following picture:

[image]

As you can see the `/media` is taking the largest amount. However, this is a external HD where I backup my system. So why does it get counted as disk space? Is there a way to avoid this behaviour or am I really forced to delete some old backups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that `/media` is an `external HD where I backup my system`. But, your `df` output does not list that as a separate mount point.

Perhaps you had the external drive mounted there at some point, but the simplest explanation is that you don't, now, for some reason, and so `/media` is just a subdirectory on `/`.

This theory fits well with your `ncdu` report, which shows ~63 GiB in `/media`. That plus the other parts of the tree also on the same `/dev/sda1` where `/` is mounted add up to around the ~78 GiB shown by `df`.

Comment: it seems this is the case. looks like my external hd (old one) just dont work anymore and rsnapshot wrote directly on the disk when it couldn't find any mounted stuff there.